# Handling/Extracting NULL values that are available in other columns / fields

Tags: r, text, null, dataset

I have missing values in 2 columns distance and metric but the missing information are available in a different columns. I want to extract the values and paste them in the NA rows using R.

Below is an example of current data shape and the requirement:

**Current:**

| Case | Distance | Metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *jsalidjsalj; 10 KM daskdsadok; 73 saujdhuj | NA | NA |
| *dskfnsldfn sadjidisaj 500 - 550 M wqldl | NA | NA |

**Requirement:**

| Case | Distance | Metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *jsalidjsalj; **10 KM** daskdsadok; 73 saujdhuj | 10 | KM |
| *dskfnsldfn sadjidisaj **500** - 550 **M** wqldl | 500 | M |

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- tribble(
  ~Case, ~Distance, ~Metric,
  "*jsalidjsalj; 10 KM daskdsadok; 73 saujdhuj", NA, NA,
  "*dskfnsldfn sadjidisaj 500 - 550 M wqldl", NA, NA
)
data
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   Case                                        Distance Metric
#>   <chr>                                       <lgl>    <lgl> 
#> 1 *jsalidjsalj; 10 KM daskdsadok; 73 saujdhuj NA       NA    
#> 2 *dskfnsldfn sadjidisaj 500 - 550 M wqldl    NA       NA

to_numeric <- . %>%
  str_extract("[0-9]+") %>%
  as.numeric()

data %>%
  mutate(
    Distance = ifelse(is.na(Distance), str_extract(Case, "[0-9 -]+ K?M") %>% to_numeric(), Distance),
    Metric = ifelse(is.na(Metric), str_extract(Case, "K?M"), Metric)
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   Case                                        Distance Metric
#>   <chr>                                          <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1 *jsalidjsalj; 10 KM daskdsadok; 73 saujdhuj       10 KM    
#> 2 *dskfnsldfn sadjidisaj 500 - 550 M wqldl         500 M
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>